# tkinter window not coming up while using python 3.3.3 32 bit but works fine on 64 bit

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, add-in, enterprise-architect

If i run the script directly(using python command), it works both on 32 as well as 64 bit python 3.3.3 installation.
But my task is to integrate(As Addin/Extension) it to Enterprise Architect and execute the script.

Below is my source code and the screenshots with errors.

```
import win32com.client
import pythoncom
import ctypes
import sys
from tkinter import * 
import glob
import shutil
import sys
import os
from tkinter import filedialog

class Application():              
    def __init__(self, master=None):
            mGui =  Tk()
            mGui.geometry('400x80')
            mGui.title('Choose the template directory        ')
            mEntry = Entry(mGui,width=50,state="readonly",font=("Arial", 8,"bold")).grid(row=0,column=0,padx=(15),pady=(15))

            mButton = Button(mGui,text='Browse',font=("Arial", 8,"bold")).grid(row=0,column=1)
            mButton = Button(mGui,text='Save',font=("Arial", 8,"bold")).grid(row=1,column=0,padx=(15),pady=(2))           
            mGui.mainloop()

class EAAddin():
   _public_methods_ = ['EA_FileOpen', 'EA_GetMenuItems', 'EA_MenuClick']
   _reg_progid_ = "EAAddin"
   _reg_clsid_ = pythoncom.CreateGuid() 



   def EA_FileOpen(self, repo_obj):
    "Callback EA_FileOpen"
    repo = win32com.client.Dispatch(repo_obj)

    print("ConnectionString = ", repo.ConnectionString)

   def EA_GetMenuItems(self, repo_obj, menuLocation, menuName):
    "Callback EA_GetMenuItems"
    if menuName == "":        
        return "-EAAddin"
    else:
        menuOptions=[]
        menuOptions.append("Export")
        menuOptions.append("Templates Path")
        return menuOptions 



   def EA_MenuClick(self, repo_obj, menuLocation, menuName, itemName):
    "Callback EA_MenuClick" 
    app = Application()  
if __name__ == "__main__":

   print("Registering COM server...") 
   try:  
    import win32com.server.register
    win32com.server.register.UseCommandLine(EAAddin)
   except BaseException:
       print(BaseException)
```

The Screenshot for 64 bit version are below.
I click on the Addin
[image]

The result-

[image]

The Screenshot for 32 bit version are below.
I click on the Addin
[image]

The result-

[image]

Please let me know if there is something i need to do.

Comment: The default `baseName` comes from `sys.argv[0]`. Maybe it's `bytes` for some reason (embedding error?). Try setting it explicitly: `mGui = Tk(baseName="testing_html")`.